# Book - A girl who gets possessed by a doll of a dead spirit in a coastal village?

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

I've read a translation of this book about 10 years ago. The original book is probably English, because it had English names as I recall. I'm not very good with remembering the names. The language of the book I read was in Sinhala. I'm sorry but I don't know the year that the original book came out.

A teenage girl moves into a new home in a coastal village with her family. She's adopted and her adopted mother is pregnant at the time when the story starts.

The teenager finds a mysterious doll in the new home. She gives it a name, I think it begins with A (Amelia, maybe. Not sure). The doll starts talking to her and making her do things. It's revealed the doll is controlled by the evil spirit of a dead girl who died years ago. The teenager gets more and more infatuated with the doll and kills one or two kids from the village who are mean to her (it's unclear who actually carries out the kills: she or the spirit).

At the end, the girl commits suicide. The epilogue shows her newborn younger sister discovering the same doll and gives it her dead older sister's name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Comes the Blind Fury* (1980) by John Saul.

From [this Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1489771027?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1) (which is much more descriptive than [the official summary](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/239887.Comes_the_Blind_Fury)):

> The Pendleton family arrive at their new home in Paradise Point (a village a couple of hours northeast of Boston). Dr. Calvin Pendleton has switched jobs, from working at a hospital in Boston, to a small clinic in Paradise Point. [...] **So Cal moves from Boston to Paradise Point with his family---his pregnant wife June, and their twelve-year-old adopted daughter Michelle.**
>
> **One day, while unpacking, Michelle finds an old-fashioned antique doll in her closet and she names it Amanda.** She later finds out from her friends at school that there's rumors of a ghost that roams the cliffs of Paradise Point---**the ghost of a twelve-year-old blind girl that fell off the cliff to her death after being taunted by her classmates over a hundred years ago, and her name was Amanda. Michelle and her friends find it odd that she happened to name the doll Amanda.** And Michelle is also starting to have dreams, and visions, of a small girl, dressed in black, wearing old-fashioned clothes, calling to her. One day, while at a picnic with some friends at the cove, Michelle gets picked on and taunted/teased for being adopted. Her mother recently gave birth to a new daughter, Jenny, and a cruel classmate suggests her parents won't love her anymore. Hurt, Michelle runs away, and has an accident. She now has trouble walking and is alone alot. **She is being picked on by the kids at school. She wants a friend, someone who loves her. Amanda seems to be calling to her. Amanda will be her friend...**

---

Found with the Google query`scifi book teenage adopted girl finds doll possession site:goodreads.com/book` (page 2 of the results).